# Error: Can not find or load the main class com.example.demo.DemoApplication

Tags: spring, eclipse

i use spring STS meven and tomcat eclipse
all that is installed succesfuly
i imported the project from spring-initialiser 
but i can't run my project 
any help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not changed any codes and using exact code from spring initializer, it should work fine.

Make sure .class file is generated and it's in build path.

If above is ok then clean your workspace.
Go to your workspace, delete .metadata directory (or to be safe, copy the directory somewhere else to be safe)